# SQL Inventory email

Tags: sql, email, inventory

I am pretty new to SQL and have a client that want's email updates when an item falls under a certain threshold.  Having an issue with the "If exists" statements

This is as far as I have gotten

```
where ClientNumber = 9999 
and   Sku like '[_]%' 
and   onhand < 1000 
and   StatusID = '6' 
and   sku NOT like '%FOY%' 
and   sku not like '_Book%'

if exists
@email
```

So basically if it pulls up a row I want to email the client the data. Just FYI those "NOT like" statements are because they don't care at all about those certain SKUs.

Comment: which rdbms (sql-server, oracle, mysql, postgresql)?  Are you wanting only the query to check for when it falls under threshold (if so post example data)?  Actual method of being able to send an email?  Way to write a trigger on the table(s)?  right now all that exists above is a where statement with no select, tables, etc.  please add additional detail to your question

Answer (score 0):

"if exists" checks for rows matching a *select* so your code could be structured like this:

```
if exists (select id from myitemtable where onhand < 200)
begin
  << send email routine >>
end
```